# How to exit powershell script if window name exists?

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-4.0

I can get a list of current open windows like this:

`Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle} | format-table mainWindowTitle`

How do I write proper syntax to loop and check if Window Name exists and then exit?

Below is the logic I would like to execute:

```
# BASIC-esque CONDITIONAL LOGIC
# FILENAME: CheckWindowName.ps1

Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle} | format-table mainWindowTitle

# LOOP START - Loop through $_.mainWindowTitle / mainWindowTitle

If $_.mainWindowTitle CONTAINS "*notepad*" Then
    Exit #break script
Else
    Echo "Hello World! There are no instances of notepad open"
End If

# LOOP END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle} | ForEach {
    #iterates through processes here. each one can be referenced by $_
}
```

A basic introduction into how `ForEach-Object` works can be found on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx)

Comment: tks, can you expand on the `#iterates through processes here. each one can be referenced by $_` logic?

Comment: Please research "PowerShell foreach loop" to learn more.
For now, just run this:  
if (ps notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {'Notepad is open'}

Answer (score 1):

Try to use -like instead of contains. It worked for me.

Below is the example:

PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -like "*notepad*" }

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
     71       7     1516       6760    95     0.23   6328 notepad
     71       7     1516       6676    95     0.11   7212 notepad
     68       7     1472       2808    94     8.14   7364 notepad
     73       7     1540       1568    95     0.48   8640 notepad
     74       8     1820       1672   160     9.41   8884 notepad

Comment: use wild card  * in front of notepad and after notepad.